# Mostrar mensagem de alerta sem causar exceção

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, tsql

Gostaria de mostrar uma mensagem de alerta para o usuário sem causar exceção na procedure. Estou usando o SQL Server. Então não posso utilizar `RAISERROR`, nem `PRINT`, pois não é mostrado para o usuário.

Existe uma forma de mostrar um alertbox para o usuário sem parar a procedure?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece um pouco vaga. Você tem algum código para possamos te ajudar? Por favor, adicione **[um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** do seu código para melhores esclarecimentos.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que não. Em geral, nada que ocorre no servidor SQL é mostrado pelo usuário, e todo acesso ao banco de dados é realizado por intermédio de um software que constitui a aplicação.

Isso significa que uma alertbox por exemplo, não funcionaria mesmo se essa opção existisse, pois ou esse alertbox iria ser mostrada no servidor SQL, e a aplicação não o veria e muito menos o usuário, ou teria que ser notificado de algum jeito para a aplicação exibir, o que depende do comportamento da aplicação e não do SQL Server.

Assim sendo, o melhor que você pode fazer neste caso é alterar o formato de retorno da procedure/function para incluir um campo que contenha uma mensagem e fazer a aplicação olhar para esse campo também e tratá-lo adequadamente para que a aplicação que está a invocar a procedure mostre o alertbox.

Uma outra possibilidade é colocar os alertas em uma tabela específica para essa finalidade usando um `INSERT` e fazer com que a aplicação ou algum outro processo consulte essa tabela mostrando a mensagem para o usuário.